# How to extend C void function to python using SWIG?

Tags: python, swig

If I have a C function like this:

```
y = myfunc(x){
   y = x + 2;
}
```

I know how to write the *.i file and make the above function callable in Python. But if I have a C function like this:

```
void encode(int x[], int len, int y[]){
     int i;
     for (i=0; i<len; i++){
         y[i] = x[i] * 2;
     }
}
```

I do not know how to write the *.i interface and failed to find over the internet. Anyone could give me some hint?

Comment: `int y[]` is essentially a pointer to int, that is `int*`

Comment: Check this http://swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIG.html#SWIG_nn16

Comment: show the first case. Then show what you attempted for the second and explain what went wrong

Comment: `y = myfunc(x){` is not a function definition. Please post the proper definition, together with the *.i* file, and the attempts for the 2nd *.i* file.